# Javascript is not rendering in viewpager (Webview Fragments)

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a viewpager containing webview. In webview long press performs using `onCreateContextMenu`. I want to color my selected text on webview but the problem is javascript is called only on the first page. If we reload webview every time it's working fine but viewpager performance isn't looking good.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should provide your code whenever you ask for help with it. Also I recommend reading how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it will great help if you will give solution.!